# Creating isochrones in QGIS using QNEAT3

Tags: qgis, isochrone

I am trying to make transport accessibility map in QGIS, using QNEAT3 plugin to build isochrones. I need to make a map, that shows 30 minutes area of accessibility with 5 minutes interval zones.
I am using **Iso-Area as Polygons (from Layer)** option and **Fastest Path (time optimization)** in **Path type to calculate**.

[image]
[image]
I can't understand what units should i use in **Size of Iso-Area** and **Contour Interval**. I was trying to enter *hours* (0,5 for 30 mins and 0,083 for 5 mins) as in advanced parameters default speed is in km/h. But with this small values plugin doesn't work.

```
band_in = ds_in.GetRasterBand(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'
```

As far as I understand it is because 
QNEAT can't make a single cell to create a raster file.

The question is: what values/units should I use if I want to get time (not distance) accessibility?

Comment: From my personal tests i would say it is in seconds. But I encountered the same problem as you when using QGIS 3.8. Having no problems when using QGIS 3.4 (exactly the same settings) though. Which version do you use?

Comment: I am using QGIS 3.4.6. Following to you and setting values in seconds, result appears truthful to me, thanks! But i should notice that if you have optional parameter **Speed field** in **Advanced parameters**, it must be set in _km/h_ not in _km/sec_, or you will have the same issue.

Comment: If your question is solved, you can post your comment as answer, so it will help others having the same question.

Answer (score 4):

You should use *seconds* in **Size of Iso-Area** and **Contour Interval**. Also, if you have optional parameter **Speed field**, it's input should be in *km/h*.