# QGIS QNEAT3 AttributeError by creating isodistances/isochrones

Tags: qgis-3, routing, network

Trying to generate isodistances/isochrones in the QNEAT 3 plugin I got the following error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\algs\IsoAreaAsPolygonsFromPoint.py",
> line 249, in processAlgorithm polygon_featurelist =
> net.calcIsoPolygons(max_dist, interval, output_path) File
> "C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\Qneat3Framework.py",
> line 469, in calcIsoPolygons band_in = ds_in.GetRasterBand(1)
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'
> Execution failed after 53.74 seconds
```

Parameters:

[image: parameters]

All layers are in a projected CRS. Matplotlib library in the OSGeo4W Shell has been installed.

I am using QGIS 3.6.1

I have tried to play a bit with different parameters but without success (seems it doesn´t have any influence on the error message). Besides I still don´t understand the meaning of the contour interval parameter...?

[QNEAT3 infopage](https://root676.github.io/IsoAreaAlgs.html)

Related thread (but unfortunately didn´t answer my question).

[Creating isochrones in QGIS using QNEAT3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328606/creating-isochrones-in-qgis-using-qneat3)

Any thoughts why I´m getting this error?

UPDATE:
Changing the parameters so the contour interval >> raster size:

[image: parameters_02]

After reprojecting the network layer to a projected CRS via the appropriate geoprocessing tool:

[image: isochrones]

Comment: Did my answer below help? Or do you still run into errors?

Comment: Via the contour interval you can set the number of isochrones/isodistances. So when the size of the Iso-Area is 2,500 m and the contour interval is 500 m, 5 polygons will be generated. The raster size should be therefore always lower then the contour interval (now it makes sense) to find the appropriate pattern. To answer your second question: No, I still get the same "GetRasterband" error.

Comment: CRS: EPSG:5243 - ETRS89 / LCC Germany (E-N) - Projected (layer + project); default speed: 5km/h. To speed up the calculations I have created a subset of roads layer (clip by polygon, radius ca. 5 km). Layer is from GEOFABRIK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should once again think about the parameters you chose. QNEAT3 uses an interpolation raster for creating the isochrones on a network. You chose a cell size of `1000x1000m` and entered a contour interval of `1m`. How should the contour algorithm find a contour in a single 1x1km raster cell? Switch the parameters to a 1x1m cell size and a suitably large contour interval level. Then you won't get the error about a missing raster layer.

Comment: Well the problem was associated with the wrong CRS. The Geofabrik layers have WGS84 as CRS. To set the CRS in the project doesn´t suffice. The layers have to be reprojected in a projected CRS (via the appropriate tool). Then the raster error dissappears cause the calculations now base on the actual projected CRS. Neverthless many thanks for your help.